# Dual boot - 12.04 installed first

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I have found many guides with how to install windows and ubuntu in dual boot mode, but none from the perspective of a Ubuntu user. Unfortunately Wine or OpenOffice do not display a document that I am working on properly so I am forced to getting windows back temporarily.

Can anyone give me some guidance on how to go about this, sorry but step by step instructions are needed as I am still fairly new to Linux

Comment: You could use a virtual machine installation; you would have to get someone familiar with how to do that to help you but....If you only need it for ONE document and then done, have you tried to use google documents? it is supposed to be compatible with all documents and you can save, share and print them form google's server.  Just a thought, might save you some time if it works..

Answer (score 0):

An excellent alternative to dual boot is to use VirtualBox, which is available in the Software Center. With VirtualBox, you install and run Windows within a running copy of Ubuntu. I used to dual-boot, but I found VirtualBox to work better, since I do not have to reboot the computer to get into Windows and can even save the machine state so that I do not have to wait for the sluggish Microsoft operating system to boot.