# How do I dual boot Windows given that I have already installed Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows

All the literature I can find about dual booting Windows and Ubuntu suggests that Windows be installed first, then Ubuntu, since the Ubuntu install software has an option that streamlines this whole process.

I already installed Ubuntu and have been using it for a few months, and I don't want to just wipe everything in order to install Windows and then reinstall Ubuntu.  I am also a bit new at this, so I don't know the appropriate way to partition my drive to install Windows manually.

> Is there a way to dual boot Windows easily given an existing Ubuntu install?

I have combed the Internet for a good guide on this topic but I haven't found anything yet that I understand.  What I am really looking for is a simple guide that doesn't involve advanced terminology or lingo (picture based, even, if possible).  I am slowly learning what all this linux terminology means, but I am still a beginner, and am nowhere near able to understand everything that I apparently have to to accomplish this task.

Comment: You could virtualize windows (using vmware), or you could look at this question http://askubuntu.com/q/6317/169736

Answer (score 0):

I know what is your problem and I think this might partially answer your question even though I would not personally be satisfied with this resolution [Dual boot - 12.04 installed first](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156446/dual-boot-12-04-installed-first?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

You need a primary partition (sda1 thru sda4) formatted NTFS with the boot flag. Windows will automatically install its boot loader to the MBR, so you need your Ubuntu live installer or a repairCD to fix/repair grub in the MBR.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

All of above assumes BIOS with MBR partitioning. If you have BIOS and gpt partitioning you cannot install Windows as Windows only boots from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI.

If you have UEFI you should just need to create space as Windows wants several partitions.

Comment: Apologies in advance- I don't mean to sound ungreatful- but, this is precisely the type of explanation I read and did not understand.  I am a beginner.  What do these abbreviations mean?  How do I tell if I have this stuff?