# 'Package not in database' when restoring with dpkg --set-selections

Tags: package-management, dpkg

I just reinstalled Ubuntu MATE 15.10 from scratch. I had followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/334362/149408) to save a list of installed packages and restore it on the newly installed system.

However, when I do

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < packages-backup.list
```

I get a long list of error messages like these:

```
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1417: sqlite3
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1417: sqliteman
dpkg: warning: package not in database at line 1417: sqliteman-doc
```

and finally

```
dpkg: warning: found unknown packages; this might mean the available database is outdated, and needs to be updated through a frontend method
```

So I ran `sudo apt-get update` and re-ran `dpkg` but I keep getting the same error.

I seem to get this error message for every single package in the list, including rather unspectacular ones such as the default kernel or sqlite. Also, I had not added any additional PPAs on my previous setup, thus packages from non-default repositories can't be the issue here.

As a test, I tried to install one of the "offending" packages with `sudo apt-get install`, which worked without any issues.

What's going wrong here?

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade`?

Comment: Not yet (as In understand the answer, this would be run afterwards). Just found something similar in the `dpkg` manpage and ran `sudo dselect update`, then retried. That reduced the warnings to packages that explicitly state a particular version.

Comment: Just executed `sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade` and it seems to be installing everything that's missing. Looks like all is fine now...

Comment: In this case I'll add an answer, then you can close the question.

Comment: one note on Ubuntu 16.10 desktop install, I had to  'apt-get install dselect' for this to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warnings are safe to ignore, as they only concern the `dpkg` database. Actual installation is done with APT, which doesn't use this database.

When you are using `dpkg` in this manner, you need to use `dselect-upgrade` in order to apply the changes marked.

```
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade
```

From man **dpkg**:

> Note that this file is mostly useless if
>    you don't use dselect but an APT-based frontend: APT has its own system to keep track of available packages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since I run `dselect-upgrade` after `set-selections`, I understand I would still get the warnings – are you saying they're safe to ignore as they refer to a package DB that isn't going to be used anyway?

Comment: @user149408, that is correct, you can safely ignore those. Trust whatever APT says, which will be the one that manages existing packages from then on.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install dselect && sudo dselect update
```

After you can execute:

```
sudo dpkg --set-selections < packages-backup.list
```

Comment: Thank you, this actually solves the problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

This method does not require `dselect` package

To update dpkg database from apt cache:

```
apt-get update # can skip this
apt-cache dumpavail > /var/cache/apt/available
dpkg --admindir=/var/lib/dpkg --update-avail /var/cache/apt/available
```

Or one-liner with root:

```
dpkg --admindir=/var/lib/dpkg --update-avail <(apt-cache dumpavail)
```

Comment: While other answers provide information that is true, this is the real solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

In recent versions of Debian/Ubuntu/Mint, `dpkg` needs available packages to be in its "avail" database for **`dpkg --set-selections`** to work.

Example sequence:

1. (On other system) **`dpkg --get-selections > installed.dselect`**
2. **`sudo apt update`**
3. **`apt-cache dumpavail | sudo dpkg --merge-avail`**
4. **`sudo dpkg --set-selections < installed.dselect`**
5. **`sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade`**

The third command populates dpkg's "avail" database.  It's important to run this *before* setting the selections of which additional packages to install.

This reqires dpkg v1.17.7 and later.  See [Q: Why does ''dpkg --set-selections'' not record selections for unknown packages?](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_Why_does_.27.27dpkg_--set-selections.27.27_not_record_selections_for_unknown_packages.3F) on the Debian wiki for more details.

Answer (score 0):

The following script was a workaround for me. Watch out for linux-images and linux-headers. If you have many of those in your dpkglist.txt then you might want to filter these out with grep -v commands like

```
 cat dpkglist.txt | grep "$l_mode" | grep -v linux-headers | grep -v linux-image-3 | grep -v linux-image-extra-3 | cut -f1
```

**script to install and uninstall packages from dpkglist.txt via apt-get**

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#
# get the packages
# 
# param 1: l_mode: install or deinstall
#
packages() {
  local l_mode="$1"
  # get the lines for the given mode
  cat dpkglist.txt | grep "$l_mode" |  cut -f1
}

#
# loop over the packages in the given mode
# param 1: l_mode: install or deinstall
#
loop() {
  local l_mode="$1"
  for package in $(packages $l_mode)
  do
    case "$l_mode" in
      install) apt-get -y install $package;;
      deinstall) apt-get -y remove $package;;
    esac
  done
}

# do two loops
loop deinstall
loop install
```